# How to add object into another object in my case

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to push multiple variable into an array

I have something like

```
var tests = [];
var id = 1;
var prop1 = 1
var prop2 = 2
var prop3 = 3
```

and I do

```
tests.push({id:id {prop1:prop1,prop2:prop2,prop3:prop3}}) 
//gave me unexpected token : error
```

Basically I want to create another object that contain `prop1` to `prop3` and put it inside the id object. Is there a way to complete it within one line of codes? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your current example has a syntax error.

Comment: Less lines of code != better code. This code has syntax errors AFAICS (id:id {prop1:.....}} missing , and property name bebtween id:id and { prop1:...

Comment: Also, in the above example, once you fix syntax errors, id is not an object, it's a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there is a syntax error in your object.

try this:

```
var tests = [];
var id = 1;
var prop1 = 1
var prop2 = 2
var prop3 = 3
tests.push({id:1, props: {prop1:prop1,prop2:prop2,prop3:prop3}})
```

This assigns your properties object to a key in your object.

now you have an array with an object that has an id, and properties.

```
[{
    id:1, 
    props: {
        prop1:prop1,
        prop2:prop2,
        prop3:prop3
    }
 }]
```